How to rebuild "~/.local/share" after switching distributions
I recently switched from Ubuntu LTS to Debian 12 bookworm.  I'm having issues with default application settings so would like to create a 'fresh' ~/.local/share (or perhaps even better ~/.local) folder that matches the apps in bookworm, but if I look in /etc/skel/, there's no .local/ folder.
I can someone help me understand how the .local folder is generated and/or updated?

Figured out how to rebuild it. Simply remove ~/.local/share and logout and then login and it will get rebuilt.
